# My live AdMob ads in my app are not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have an AdMob account, which is almost a week old now.

I have developed an app for Android, and I have implemented AdMob into it.

I first tested using test ad units, and these worked fine.

However, when I changed these to the real ad units for live production, ads were not showing. On my AdMob dashboard, I got loads of requests but 0 impressions.

Instead I was getting error code 3 which basically means advertisers are not targeting my country, but when I put my device as a test device, the ads loaded up fine.

[Image of AdMob dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRrIj.png)

I have tried to use a signed apk, but this has not worked.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? I really need these ads up and running.

**Here is my XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sky Q" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sky HD" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="PLACEHOLDER-LIVEADS-ID"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is my Activity code**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AdView mAdView;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private PageAdapter pageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        String ip = sp.getString("IP_ADDRESS","_");

        if(ip == "_"){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("First time use");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Welcome to our app! To get started, go to Settings and change your IP address or search for Sky boxes automatically");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PreferenceActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.about){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("About this app");
            builder.setMessage("Developed by Joda Studios\nPublished by Joda Studios");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.help){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HelpPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a usual thing from AdMob. Advertisers are not interested in your country's users right now. Maybe this situation will be changed in the future and your users will get the ads.

Anyway, you can target users from other countries and the ads should be showing.

Also, you are able to integrate ads into your application from another advertisement platform. I recommend using Appodeal or Facebook Ads.

Comment: Thanks. I thought advertisers are always interested in UK users but it seems like I was wrong.

Comment: You are welcome! They may be interested in, but use another platform for advertisement :)